# Unable to use correct ChromeDriver version

Tags: google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I am conducting QA automation testing. The code was running and working fine last week, but on restarting my computer over the weekend, it has stopped working with this error message:

```
Request failed with status 500 due to session not created: 
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 103
```

I assume it auto-updated Chrome when I restarted the laptop, as it's gone from version 103 to 105, which means I need to update my ChromeDriver.

I've done this before a few months ago, can't totally remember the steps I followed but I got it working. I possibly did something wrong then, as I can't seem to update ChromeDriver from 103 to 105.

I've tried to remove my current instance and reinstall the newer version by running:

```
npm uninstall chromedriver -g
npm install -g chromedriver --detect_chromedriver_version --scripts-prepend-node-path
```

Also tried the same having downloaded it from here:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=105.0.5195.52/
and doing

```
npm install -g chromedriver --chromedriver_filepath=<PATH>
```

Also tried removing chromedriver from my package.json, doing an npm install, then adding it back in and doing an npm install. Each of these methods say they have installed the correct chromeDriver version (105.0.5195.52)

My package.json currently shows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^105.0.0",
  },
```

and when I do chromeDriver -v I see:

```
ChromeDriver 105.0.5195.52
```

Any ideas? If additional information is required please let me know. I know I could probably get around this by downgrading my Chrome version to 103, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, I think it's something to do with selenium. Running my tests on their own works, but if I do selenium-standalone start and then run them, it's failing as above.

I've updated selenium by running:

```
npm install selenium-standalone@latest -g
npm install
```

Following that, when I try to start it, it's giving me an error that chromedriver is missing within the selenium node_modules folder.

A bit more investigation and I've found I also needed to run

```
selenium-standalone install
```

This did some updating, and then I was able to run

```
selenium-standalone start
```

All good now :)